# convolution $ \left( {\varphi * \psi } \right)\left( x \right) = \int\limits_R {\varphi \left( {x - t} \right)\psi \left( t \right)dt} $

Tags: real-analysis

good morning
i want   like to correct the work

$
\begin{array}{l}
 \varphi \left( x \right) = \chi _{\left[ {0;2} \right]} \left( x \right);\quad \psi \left( t \right) = \left| t \right|e^{ - t^2 } \chi _{\left[ { - 1;1} \right]} \left( t \right) \\ 
 \left( {\varphi  * \psi } \right)\left( x \right) = \int\limits_R {\varphi \left( {x - t} \right)\psi \left( t \right)dt}  = \int\limits_0^2 {te^{ - t^2 } \chi _{\left[ { - 1;1} \right]} \left( t \right)}  \\ 
  =  - \frac{1}{2}\left[ {e^{ - t^2 } } \right]_0^2  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {1 - e^{ - 4} } \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to properly take into account $\phi(x-t)$. Seeing as your function doesn't depend on $x$ in the end, you should see that something weird happened.

Anyways given $\phi(x) = \chi_{[0,2]}(x)$ we have that $\phi(x-t) = \chi_{[0,2]}(x-t)$ and so 
$$
\phi(x-t) = \begin{cases} 1 &  0 \le x - t \le 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
\phi(x-t) = \begin{cases} 1 & x - 2 \le t \le x \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} = \chi_{[x-2,x]}(t)
$$

So now we get that
$$
(\phi * \psi)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x-t) \psi(t) \, \mathrm{d} t = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{[x-2,x]}(t) \cdot t e^{-t^2} \chi_{[-1,1]} \, \mathrm{d} t = \int_{x-2}^x t e^{-t^2} \chi_{[-1,1]} \, \mathrm{d} t
$$

Now if $x < -1$ or $x > 3$ then $(\phi * \psi)(x) = 0$ otherwise we will be integrating over the set $[-1,1] \cap [x-2,x] = [\max\{x-2,-1\}, \min\{x, 1\}]$ so that
$$
(\phi * \psi)(x) = \int_{\max\{x-2,-1\}}^{\min\{x, 1\}} t e^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t = \left[ - \frac{1}{2} e^{-t^2} \right]_{\max\{x-2,-1\}}^{\min\{x, 1\}}
$$
so for $-1 \le x \le 3$ we have
$$
(\phi * \psi)(x) = -\frac{1}{2} \begin{cases} 0 & x = 1 \\
e^{-1} - e^{-(x-2)^2} & x \ge 1 \\
e^{-x^2} - e^{-1} & x \le 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
thus finally for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
(\phi * \psi)(x) = -\frac{1}{2} \begin{cases} 0 & x = 1 \lor x < -1 \lor x > 3 \\
e^{-1} - e^{-(x-2)^2} & x \ge 1 \\
e^{-x^2} - e^{-1} & x \le 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: vry nice   thanc you